# Open Session in View or DTO solution

Tags: spring, session, jsf, transactionscope

I was wondering if this recipe does not use Open Session in View or Dozer works (the scenario is a spring, jsf, hibernate application):

I have this in back-end module:

```
public abstract class AbstractMap<E extends Serializable> implements Mapper<E>  {

    public abstract E map(E e) ;

        public List<E> map(List<E> l) {

        List<E> map = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (E t : l) {
            map.add(this.map(t));
        }
        return map;
    }
}

@Component
public class PersonService extends AbstractService<Person>{

    @Autowired
    PersonDAO personDao;

    @Transacted
    public List<Person> findPeople(Mapper<Person> m, PersonFilter filter) {

        return m.map(personDao.findByFilter(filter));
    }   
}
```

In front-end I have this jsb bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class PersonBean {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    PersonFilter personFilter;

    List<Person> getPeople() {

     return personService.findPeople(new AbstractMap<People>() {

     public Person map(Person person) {

             Person dto = new Person();
             dto.setName(person.getName());
             dto.setAddresses(new AbstractMap<Address>() {

                public Address map(Address a) {

                    Address dto = new Address();
                    dto.setStreet(a.getStreet());
                    return dto;
                }
             }.map(person.getAddresses()));

         return dto;
        }
        }, personFilter);
    }
}
```

From my point of view has some advantages:

- front-end must to indicate that it want to retrieve every invocation to back-end.
- if need use a mapper in more than a place, I can move map code to a external class.
- back-end open and close transaction.
- don't need duplicate code to define DTOs for Person and Address.

What problems that could cause this proposed solution?